# Why doesn't grep ignore binary files by default?

Tags: grep

The manpage for `grep` describes the `-I` flag as follows:

```
-I      Ignore binary files.  This option is equivalent to 
        --binary-file=without-match option.
```

It also says this about binary files:

```
 --binary-files=value Controls searching and printing of binary files.
         Options are binary, the default: search binary files but do not print
         them; without-match: do not search binary files; and text: treat all
         files as text.
```

I cannot think of a scenario where I would care about matches in binary files. If such a scenario exists, surely it must be the exception rather than the norm. Why doesn't `grep` ignore binary files by default rather than requiring setting this flag to do so?

Comment: You can set the variable `GREP_OPTIONS` to your preferred settings, then you don't have to use that many command line switches.

Comment: A note for other commands that do not support such a variable: You can set default options by defining an alias in your `.(ba|z|foo)shrc': `alias grep="grep -I"`.

Comment: This can actually be very useful.
For example, I was searching for the unity version of a project, and couldn't remember which file it was kept in. I searched for the format of the version, and it came up with some binary files that matches. It turned out as it was pre-version 5, the version was only present in a binary file, so without the binary match, I might have missed it.

Comment: FYI There's a tool [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) which is  kind of "better than grep". Ack doesn't search binary files. In Debian, it comes under the name "ack-grep".

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Not everything that grep thinks is a binary file, is actually a binary file. e.g. puppet's logs have ansi color coding in them, which makes grep think they're binary. I'd still want to search them if I'm grepping through /var/log though.

Comment: The same goes for PDF files as well.

Comment: + historically grep could NOT do that, so for compatibility only, default have to be all-inclusive.

Comment: @OlivierDulac it makes sense, otherwise ignoring binary files should be the default.

Answer (score 11):

`grep`’s ability to search binary files is also useful when I’m compiling a program and the linker (`ld`) complains about some function not being found. 
I can use a command like

```
grep function_name /lib/lib*
```

to find the library which contains it.  (Libraries are binary files.)

Comment: In that case, you'd rather use `grep -l function_name /lib/lib*` or `nm -Do /lib/lib* | grep function_name` or `ldconfig -p | grep -o '/.*/lib.*' | xargs nm -Do | grep function_name` though.

Comment: Well, `grep some_function /lib/*` is shorter and usually gives correct answer - name of library I am looking for. But yes, sometimes more sophisticated approach like your ones is required too.

Answer (score 2):

To process a binary file or a file that grep thinks is a binary file, use

```
grep --binary-files=text "data" f1 f2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of _why_ the behaviour is like it is, nor is even useful in the context where one says they "cannot think of a scenario where I would care about matches in binary files". Note that the opposite, ignoring binary files, which is actually useful in that context was already mentioned in the question.